# Error occurs only in debug mode

Tags: php

I have a web application, which executes fine in the browser but its throwing the error while run/debug using the Eclipse. Why is this happening?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Supposedly because these errors are only showing up in debug mode. If you told us what errors you are seeing specifically, maybe you'll get a real answer.

Comment: the following error I'm getting in console window    "PHP Warning:  Module 'json' already loaded in Unknown on line 0"

Comment: Do you have different PHP versions in Eclipse and on your server? Also different error reporting settings?

Comment: No i don't have different PHP versions in Eclipse and on my server and I don't know whether I have different error reporting settings or not. How to identify this...?

Answer (score 3):

My guess is your server is not configured to display errors while your debug environement is.
Check the php documentation : [error_reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) and [display_errors](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors)

Your dev server should be configured as to display errors (`error_display=On` in your php.ini) and the level of error reporting should be `E_ALL | E_STRICT`.

On your real server, errors should not be displayed but [logged in a file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.log-errors) instead. And I encourage you to use the [error](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) and [exception](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php) handlers to display some usefull message to your user when some fatal error occur.

Comment: in phph.ini error reporting is  "error_reporting  =  E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE"   Is this ok. or should I change or should I add anything else....

Comment: If it is a development server, you should change it for E_ALL | E_STRICT so every error, warning and notice is shown.
If it is your production server, same thing but set display_error to Off and log_error to On so your errors are logged somewhere but not visible to your users.